# Gstreamer-0.10 code failed to stream webcam video over udp

Tags: c, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer, multimedia

OS : Ubuntu
Gstreamer version 0.10

I have to develop an app to stream video from webcam to remote pc via udp.
I have written a small piece of code but it runs for a second and then throws error.

Error I am getting is

```
*Running...
Error: Internal data flow error.
Returned, stopping playback
Deleting pipeline*
```

Can someone please pinpoint me about my mistake.
Below is my code

```
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink,  *muxer,  *videoenc, *payloader, *udpsink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GMainLoop *loop;
  // Initialize GStreamer
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new( NULL, FALSE );
  // Create the elements
   source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
  muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("qtdemux", "mux");
  // videoenc = gst_element_factory_make("ffdec_mpeg4", "videoenc"); //why this failed
    videoenc = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "videoenc");// but this passed but in both cases app failed to run
   payloader = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp4vpay", "rtpmp4vpay");
   udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink");

  // Create the empty pipeline
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source )
  {
    g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if( !muxer  )
  {
    g_printerr ("failed to create muxer Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if( !videoenc)
  {
    g_printerr ("failedto create videoenc. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }

      if( !payloader || !udpsink)
      {
          {
            g_printerr ("One element could not be created out of payloader or udpsink. Exiting.\n");
            return -1;
          }
      }

  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(payloader),
             "config-interval", 0,
             NULL);
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink),
              "host", "127.0.0.1",
              "port", 5000,
              NULL);
 // we add a message handler
   bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
   gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
   gst_object_unref (bus);


  //set der source
      g_object_set (G_OBJECT ( source ), "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);



          gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source,   videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);
              gst_element_link_many (source,  videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);


   // g_print("Linked all the Elements together\n");
      gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    // Iterate
      g_print ("Running...\n");
      g_main_loop_run (loop);

      // Out of the main loop, clean up nicely
      g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
      gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

      g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n");
      gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for comment, I will post answer and we will see what we get.

Do you definitely has to use 0.10? there is already version 1.6.1.. in Ubuntu 15.10 there is built in 1.6.. anyway..

I guess you are missing capsfilter:

```
GstElement *capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "camera_caps");
GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)YUY2,width=1280,height=720,framerate=25/1");
g_object_set (capsfilter, "caps", caps, NULL);
```

You should place it right after v4l2src element..

If this is not working, you can debug running your app with `GST_DEBUG=default:4` which should print if there was linking problem.
You can also generate [dot graph](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+11%3A+Debugging+tools) of pipeline and check if everything is linked properly..

You can speed up the debugging by rewriting the code in gst-launch shell command:

`GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2,width=1280,height=720,framerate=25/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! rtpmp4vpay ! queue ! udpsink port=5000 host=127.0.0.1`

Comment: Excellent Mate.  Actually I was still getting error after adding caps. So as you suggested I did debug and found ffmpegcolorspace and rtpmp4vpay  could not be linked together.  On command prompt when I type "gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2,width=320,height=240,framerate=20/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200"  and on Receiver "gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5200 !  application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 !  rtpjpegdepay !  jpegdec !  autovideosink" it works .

Comment: So I investigated and change ffmpegcolorspace to" jpegenc" and in payloader I change it to "rtpjpegpay" and it works. Actually I need to encode using mpeg-4 so it works for me

Comment: Also to your previous comment, Its major requirement in my project to use only gstreamer-0.10 that’s why my hands are bit tied up

Comment: So in summary, The solution you provided did not help me directly but your explanation about debug did help me. Thanks once again

Comment: just a quickie, I added couple of lines of code that you mentioned. But How would I link caps to v4l2src element.

Comment: @samprat normally as you would any element `gst_element_link(v4l2src, capsfilter);`